# Compare macros containing parentheses

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

In cygwin's `sys/time.c` file, it defines the following:

```
#define CLOCK_REALTIME (clockid_t)1
#define CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID (clockid_t)2
#define CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID (clockid_t)3
#define CLOCK_MONOTONIC (clockid_t)4
```

A program that I am trying to compile defines a macro from the above macros...

```
/* make sure we have a best effort CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC we can rely on */
#if defined(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
#define CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC CLOCK_MONOTONIC
#elif defined(CLOCK_HIGHRES)
#define CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC CLOCK_HIGHRES
#else
#define CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC CLOCK_REALTIME
#endif
```

And later checks to see if the custom macro equals another macro...

```
#if CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC != CLOCK_REALTIME
    if (clock_gettime(CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC,tp) == 0) {
        return;
    }
#endif
```

However, since the macros are defined with parentheses in them, the GCC compiler fails to successfully process them, yielding the error:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:4:36: error: missing binary operator before token "4"
 #define CLOCK_MONOTONIC (clockid_t)4
                                    ^
test.c:7:32: note: in expansion of macro 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC'
 #define CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC CLOCK_MONOTONIC
                                ^
test.c:16:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC'
 #if CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC != CLOCK_REALTIME
     ^
```

Is there some way to compare the two macros without generating an error?

Comment: The defines should *at least* add an axtra pair of parentheses: `#define CLOCK_REALTIME (clockid_t)1` -->> `#define CLOCK_REALTIME ((clockid_t)1)`

Comment: As such these macros are not conforming, they have to be usable inside `#if` expression in the way you have tried. A common strategy to ensure this would be to add `+` signs such as `#define CLOCK_REALTIME ((clockid_t)+1)`.

Comment: Inspired by: https://lwn.net/Articles/64207/

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can just change:

```
#if CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC != CLOCK_REALTIME
    if (clock_gettime(CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC,tp) == 0) {
        return;
    }
#endif
```

with

```
if (CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC != CLOCK_REALTIME) {
     if (clock_gettime(CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC,tp) == 0) {
         return;
     }
}
```

If the inequality is false in all modern compilers the code will also be optimized out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to test if a macro is defined to some other particular macro. If you need this functionality you will have to 'remember' using another macro. For example:

```
#if defined(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
#define CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC CLOCK_MONOTONIC
#define CUSTOM_CLOCK_IS_MONOTONIC
#elif defined(CLOCK_HIGHRES)
#define CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC CLOCK_HIGHRES
#define CUSTOM_CLOCK_IS_HIGHRES
#else
#define CUSTOM_CLOCK_MONOTONIC CLOCK_REALTIME
#define CUSTOM_CLOCK_IS_REALTIME
#endif
```

and later on you can test

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_CLOCK_IS_REALTIME
```